# ul height expanding when div inside li is displaced downwards

Tags: html, css, height, html-lists

I am trying to create some tabs across the top of a page.
I have a ul li div /div /li /ul. The div is dsplaced downwards to overlap the bottom border of the ul to give the tab effect:

Here's the HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/thistab">not selected</a></li>
<li id="selected"><div id="innerselected"><span>selected</span></div></li>
<li><a href="/thistab">not selected</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
ul {
border-bottom: 1px solid DarkRed;
}
li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 1px
}
#selected {
border-left: 1px solid DarkRed;
border-top: 1px solid DarkRed;
border-right: 1px solid DarkRed;
}
li a {
display: block;
padding: 2px 5px;
border-top: 1px solid #666666;
border-right: 1px solid #666666;
border-left: 1px solid #666666;
text-decoration: none;
background: gainsboro
}   
#innerselected {
padding: 2px 5px;
background: White;
position: relative;
bottom: -2px
}
#innerselected * {
position: relative;
bottom: 2px
}
</style>
```

In IE8, Safari and Chrome it looks as intended.

In IE9+ and Firefox, the ul height expands to accomodate the displaced div, leaving the 'selected' tab slightly raised and detached. I don't understand why it would do that. Any ideas how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

cracked it - need to add:

```
 vertical-align: top;
```

to the li {}